# How to avoid exposing internal component in Angular

Tags: angular

Suppose I have a `OutlookBarComponent` contains some bars like Microsoft Outlook. For each bar, there is a child component `OutlookBarItemComponent`. Both `OutlookBarComponent` and `OutlookBarItemComponent` are encapsulated in `ControlModule`, so that I can use them in another business module:

```
import { OutlookBarComponent, OutlookBarItemComponent } from 'control/control.module';

@NgModule({
  //...
  declarations: [
    OutlookBarComponent,
    OutlookBarItemComponent,
  ]
})
export class BusinessModule { }
```

This works fine.

Since `OutlookBarItemComponent` is an internal component in fact, I don't want `BusinessModule` know about it. But without importing and declaring `OutlookBarItemComponent` in `BusinessModule`, Angular complains

> 'app-outlook-bar-item' is not a known element

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to use `OutlookBarItemComponent` as internal
   component without exposing it to `BusinessModule`?
2. In this case, is it a good practice to separate the logic into `OutlookBarComponent` and `OutlookBarItemComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Item1, Angular follows ES6 modules concept, where you need to export the files in order to import in else where. Similarly, you need to declare those component under declaration property of Modules. So Angular compiler easily identifies when it came accross custom elements in template files. You also need to export if you want to use that component in another modules.

For Item2, as per general guidelines, your component needs be slim that should contain View/presentation Logic. You can move business logic to services, which can be re-used in other components. There is also smart and dumb component architecture. Smart Component will perform all the business logic related to features. dumb component will receive the data as input and used only for presentation Logic.